# Writing to/loading from a file vs. storing in GUI appdata

Tags: matlab

I am doing calculations on an image and intend to save a variable to a .mat file. When accessing the variable, would it be faster for me to load from the file or store the variable to the GUI appdata?

Also, I noticed that when I originally didn't save the variable (89x512x512 double array), it ran much faster. Is saving to a file generally time expensive?

Comment: You already have that array in memory - so storing it e.g. as `appdata` is certainly the faster alternative and, given the moderate size doesn't have any real drawback. So, no reason to store it to a file.

Comment: Alright, thanks! For simple questions such as these, should I delete the question after it has been answered or keep it up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have that array in memory - so storing it via `setappdata`/`getappdata` is certainly the faster alternative and, given the moderate size doesn't have any real drawback.

So, no reason to store it to a file, imho.
Any yes, writing stuff to a file is comparingly slow and i.e. takes a certain minimum amount of time not matter how tiny your data is.